# Abilities of my ISP to stop me from browsing

Tags: network, surveillance, isp

I visited a football site yesterday to stream a match online, and since then my connection is unstable. Like, I get connected at times and loses at times. I was over at my friends' and did the same and the network in his house was also weak while trying to visit that website, although I was able to visit the site using cellular data, later.

Can my ISP can do such a thing?

Comment: since the ISP knows the ip address when doing dns resolution,in theory the ISP can choose to slow down the connection to particular sites.

Comment: The ISP has complete control over your internet, so _of course_ they have the technical capability to block and control your access. Whether this violates your service contract or laws is another story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ISP's have the ability to arbitrarily block or throttle traffic based on the source of the traffic, or other factors.  This is what *net neutrality* aims to prevent.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_neutrality.